# Adobe Air Camera Issue

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, camera

Dont know if anyone has come across this issue but I am creating an app for mobile devices and it runs fine on my galaxy s2 running ics 4.0.4 however when I run it on the galaxy tab running 2.3.3 it keeps throwing errors.

All that I am doing is getting the device camera and attaching it to a flash.media.Video.  I have the suspicion that the amount of errors caused by this issues is severly affecting the perfomance.

I have attached an fxp file ( https://www.box.com/s/77a9460edcf8a7ce95ee ) so that you can see that I am not doing anything out of the ordinary.

THanks for your help!

P.S.

Here is a sample segment of the logcat-

D/TvOut-Engine(   79):  (isHdmiCableConnected): mHdmiCableConnected 0

D/CameraHardwareSec(   75): MemoryHeapBase(fd(26), size(5760128), width(800), height(600))

W/AudioFlinger(   75): RecordThread: buffer overflow

D/dalvikvm(12597): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1206K, 48% free 4217K/8007K, external 4034K/4493K, paused 91ms

V/AudioHardwareALSA(   75): resampler read error -32

D/AudioHardwareALSA(   75): AudioStreamInALSA::read error -32

D/AudioHardwareALSA(   75): AudioStreamInALSA::snd_pcm_recover error 0

E/v4l2_utils(   75): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf

E/CameraHardwareSec(   75): ERR(int android::CameraHardwareSec::previewThread()):overlay queueBuffer fail

I/dalvikvm-heap(12597): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.060MB for 5760016-byte allocation

D/dalvikvm(12597): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 203K, 30% free 9638K/13639K, external 3975K/4493K, paused 26ms

E/v4l2_utils(   75): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf

E/CameraHardwareSec(   75): ERR(int android::CameraHardwareSec::previewThread()):overlay queueBuffer fail

D/dalvikvm(12597): GC_CONCURRENT freed 91K, 31% free 9547K/13639K, external 3975K/4493K, paused 2ms+13ms

D/dalvikvm(12597): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 76K, 31% free 9471K/13639K, external 3975K/4493K, paused 43ms

E/v4l2_utils(   75): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf

E/CameraHardwareSec(   75): ERR(int android::CameraHardwareSec::previewThread()):overlay queueBuffer fail

I/dalvikvm-heap(12597): Grow heap (frag case) to 21.133MB for 5760016-byte allocation

E/v4l2_utils(   75): Error = Invalid argument from qbuf

E/CameraHardwareSec(   75): ERR(int android::CameraHardwareSec::previewThread()):overlay queueBuffer fail